# Sorting of countabe set

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory

Let $X$ be a countable ordered set. My question is very simple - Can we sort $X$ in countable number of steps?

When $X$ is finite, the answer is obviously yes. But what is the answer when $X$ is infinite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure.  Do bubble sort on the first n elements, and then increment n.  Gerhard "Don't Ask Me About Supertasks" Paseman, 2013.09.28

Comment: Welcome back, @GerhardPaseman! :)

Comment: Well, it's less simple than that - iterated bubble sort only works if $X$ has order type $\omega$. But we could ask this same question if $X$ is any order type, and if $X$ is well-ordered we could make sense of "a computational procedure of length $X$" (and maybe even if $X$ is not well-ordered; I vaguely remember a paper doing this, but I can't find it - it is still conceivable). In any case, I think the full answer might be less simple, and I'm not sure this question should have been closed (although it certainly needs more explanation, and a clarification of what's being asked).

Comment: I think the article I was vaguely remembering is http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~carton/Publications/Linear/Kleene/Scattered/jcss.pdf (and I should also note that "sort" is ambiguous if $X$ is not well-ordered - for example, if $X$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual order, then there $\omega$-many ways to 'list $X$ in order' if we take that to mean 'exhibit a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ which is order-preserving). I strongly encourage the OP to rewrite this question, with motivation and clear definitions; I think it could be extremely interesting.

Comment: (I have removed the clearly unrelated "number theory" tag, and added the "computability theory" tag.)

Comment: @Joel,  Thank You!  It does feel quite nice to be welcomed. Noah, it depends on what is truly wanted, and what resources are at hand.  Clearly any finite fragment of X can be ordered with e.g. bubblesort; all that is needed is some surjection of $\omega$ onto X. If the idea is to discover the order type of X, I agree that requires a bit more.  Gerhard "May Come Here More Often" Paseman, 2013.09.30

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/906/12357

Comment: @NoahS, Incidentally, this question is related to a one of the theorems showing that infinite time Turing machines are much stronger than had been expected---they can decide $\Pi^1_1$-sets of reals and more---because that proof uses a kind of sorting algorithm to count through the relation coding by an arbitrary relation on $\mathbb{N}$. See the proof of theorem 2.2 in my paper at http://jdh.hamkins.org/ittms/. Specifically, one systematically searches through the relation to find and erase the least element, and then the next least element and so on.